# How to delete a name from a cell that references another cell in order to know what to delete?

Tags: excel

I have a cell in Excel that has an address, which includes the name of the addressee at the beginning as per usual. I have another cell that has just the name of the addressee. I want to delete the name of the addressee from the full address. An example:

> Full address: Thompson, LLC 123 S Great Falls, Kansas
>
> Name of addressee: Thompson, LLC

Is there a way to reference the cell that has just the name of the addressee in order to tell the cell with the full address to delete the addressee name?

I am okay with not having to reference the cell that has just the name of the addressee in order to delete it from the cell with the full address as long as there is really a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,A2,""))
```

where A1 is the addressee and A2 is the address.

Comment: Rodrigo, it's saying I have too few arguments for this function and highlights the quotation marks as if to say this is the area that needs fixing. Any advice?

Comment: use the substitute function instead of replace function.

Comment: I am using that, but it says the same thing; i.e., that I need to select more data, etc. Any additional feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, replace the semicolon ( ; ) by comma ( , ). My Excel is in portuguese, and for portuguese the function separator is semicolon, but for english is comma. I updated the code as well at the answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straight forward approach is to use the built in Excel function: SUBSTITUTE

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,A3,"")
```

where A1 is the cell containing your full address and A3 is the cell containing the name of your addressee.